# $U(n)$ diffeomorphic to $SU(n)\times S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

This is an extract from Exercise 1.16.12 in Bröcker and tom Dieck *Representations of compact Lie groups* in which I am stuck:

> Show $U(n)\simeq SU(n)\times S^1$ as manifolds. Show that the surjective homomorphism
> $$SU(n)\times S^1 \ni (A,\xi)\mapsto \xi A \in U(n)$$
> has a cyclic kernel of order $n$.

I know that there is a short exact sequence given by
$$1\rightarrow SU(n)\overset{i}{\rightarrow} U(n) \overset{\det}{\rightarrow} S^1\rightarrow 1$$
so that by the First Isomorphism theorem I have a group isomorphism $U(1)\simeq \frac{U(n)}{SU(n)}$.

My first approach would be trying to normalize $U(n)$ elements by its determinant, but this involves taking the $n^{th}$ root and I suspect this might break continuity of the diffeomorphism I am looking for. This idea would be implemented by
$$
A \in U(n) \mapsto \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\det(A)}}A, \det(A)\right)\in SU(n)\times S^1
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for an isomorphism as manifolds, you can actually break the group structure.

Define a map $SU(n) \times S^1 \rightarrow U(n)$ sending $(A, z)$ to $A \cdot \operatorname{diag}(z, 1, \dots, 1)$. This is no longer a group homomorphism, but you can show that it is an isomorphism of manifolds by explicitly writing down its inverse, which is $A\in U(n)\mapsto (A\cdot \operatorname{diag}(\det(A)^{-1}, 1, \dots, 1), \det(A))$.